# Extract stored values in mysql table and store it in diffrent Variable per word

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database called 'info' that has a table 'details' in it. It has a field called 'listing'.
I extract the data in a row with field listing like this:

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM details WHERE id = '$id'";
$select = msqli_query($sql, $db);
$row = msqli_fetch_row($select);
$list = row['listing'];
```

The field listing has contents like: "a, b, gjshj, wuk, akk"
i want to store each word separated by comma in different variables likes list1, list2 ,list3.... untill when the table value ends..
I have no idea how to do this and which loop will complete my task..

Comment: [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) can help you.

Comment: how to add it in variables list1, list2...

Comment: `$lists = explode(',', $row['listing']);`. `$lists` will be an array with all your words.

Comment: Do an explode on $list and then loop through the resulting array, inserting them into your database seperately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```
$newArray = explode("," , $listing);
```

The result is then in an array ready to use. If you truly want to parse them into non array variables then you need to do something like this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($newArray as $key => $value){
    $i++;
    $newvar = "list" . $i;
    $$newvar = $value;
}
```

This will give you the values in listing parsed out into variables $list1, $list2 , etc.

Answer (score 1):

First create new array like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list); $i++) {
  $new_list['list'.$i] = $list[$i];
}
```

Then use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function.

> This function treats keys as variable names and values as variable
>   values. For each key/value pair it will create a variable.

```
extract($new_list);
```

Now you have vars `$list1`, `$list2`...

```
echo $list1;
```

See running in [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/RZFBzY)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM details WHERE id = '$id'";
$select = msqli_query($sql, $db);
while($row = msqli_fetch_row($select)){
    $list = $row['listing'];
    echo $list;
}
```

after execution of the query at $select,
loop the query result out by using while loop

Comment: Please also explain (in plain english) what your code is doing

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this, though I don't really get why

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM details WHERE id = '$id'";
$select = msqli_query($sql, $db);
$row = msqli_fetch_row($select);
$list = explode(',', $row['listing'];

foreach ($list as $k => $v);
    $i = $k+1;
    $list$i = $v;
}
```

The above will give you:

```
$list1 = 'a';
$list2 = 'b';
$list3 = 'c';
$list4 = 'd';
$list5 = 'e';
```

if you want to insert them in the database however, change the foreach to:

```
foreach ($list as $k => $v) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO table (columnname) VALUES ('".$v."')";
    // Do your query as you are used to (mysql, mysqli, pdo)
}
```

Hope this helps